# How to randomly select a shape to draw several using a loop?

Tags: c#, loops, random, shapes, dynamically-generated

I got stuck when i want to display my objects in a random way .
Let's say i got this pannel and let's say the rectangle and ellipse are the objects

[image: Example]

What do i need to do so i can have them display in this form.

Do i need to use `Random n = new Random` ? or there is another way.

This is one of my attemps but i dont know how to integrate the random function to display them.

```
do
{
    dr.DrawEllipse(Bpen, i + 30, 25, i + 30, 25);
    i += 50;
} 
while (i <= this.Width);
```

Comment: Let me try this and i will come with an edit. ty for spoiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array of available items like `{ squareType, circleType }`.

And then random `0..Length` on that array to select and draw the relevant shape.

For example you can use this enum:

```
public enum Shapes
{
  Circle,
  Square
}
```

And declare these members:

```
static readonly Array ShapesValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Shapes));
static readonly int ShapesCount = ShapesValues.Length;
```

And this RNG:

```
static readonly Random random = new Random();
```

So you can write:

```
int posX = 0;
do
{
  switch ( ShapesValues.GetValue(random.Next(ShapesCount)) )
  {
    case Shapes.Circle:
      // ...
      break;
    case Shapes.Square:
      // ...
      break;
    default:
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
  posX += 50;
}
while ( posX <= Width );
```

By doing this, you can define and manage any necessary shape in a clean and maintainable way.

If the shapes can have different sizes, consider handling this with intermediate variables.

You could also write this to make the code more secure:

```
static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<Shapes> ShapesValues 
  = Array.AsReadOnly(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Shapes)).Cast<Shapes>().ToArray());

static readonly int ShapesCount = ShapesValues.Count;
```

And:

```
switch ( ShapesValues[random.Next(ShapesCount)] )
```

Comment: Thanks for example , i will use it for future projects. Ofc when i will get the handle of it. Appreciate it.